# How to paste complex passwords into windows command line (shell)?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, ssh, passwords

I manage my accounts for websites with KeePass. This tool generates highly complex passwords, such as `d,ªL¹(ç,z/¬gSÑ~}ÄwÚÆ¡íµ¯ó]ó6õ?Ô£fß,`.
Such a complex password I use for example for Red Hat’s OpenShift website.

OpenShift servers/applications can be managed best by using their rhc command line tool.

Now, while running `rhc setup` I have to enter my password. So I copy it into the clipboard and paste it into the shell, where rhc sits and waits for my PW. However, the password won’t get accepted.

The process of pasting probably causes some changes. I already tried doing `chcp 1252` and `chcp 65001` before running `rhc setup`. Unfortunately this also didn’t help. The only way to get it running was changing my password to a trivial one on the OpenShift website, then doing the setup, and then changing the password back to a complex one.

Anyways, now I want to log in to my applications via `rhc ssh`, which is asking for the password of my ssh keys. And as everyone can guess, my ssh key is protected by a password in the style above. This is no problem because pasting such passwords into Putty or other GUI applications works great.

So I wonder: is there a way how I can do safe pasting into windows shells?

Comment: Realistically speaking, if you need to use these passwords at the command line, you will probably need to configure KeePass to restrict itself to printable ASCII characters.  You can always increase the length to compensate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I commend you on your passwords!

There's two major possibilities:

- Some characters need to be escaped

  - Shift to a longer password without the escape-requiring characters
  - Escape the characters!
- Code page fun, i.e. some characters are being transformed

  - Figure out the mapping and duplicate your KeePass entry with one that will map to the correct values for that login type
  - Shift to a longer password without the escape-requiring characters

Assuming your password (unlikely) is a 35 character password using all 256 possible 8 bit values, that's a maximum exhaustive keyspace of 256^35, roughly 2E84 or 2^280.  You can achieve a slightly higher maximum exhaustive keyspace with a password of 43 charactres containing Upper, Lower, Number, and normal US keyboard symbols (94^43), or 48 characters containing Upper, Lower, and Number (62^48).

The Upper, Lower, Number password of length 48 shouldn't cause any problems with escaped characters, and is far less likely to cause problems with code page transforms.

Note that both of those are likely to be superior against the edge case of an attacker who knows which characters were actually used :).

Note also that even a 35 character password containing only Upper, Lower, and Number has a maximum exhaustive keyspace of 62^35, or 5.4E62, or 2^208; 208 bits is likely to substantially exceed the amount of security provided by your transport layer and/or their storage mechanism.

*All passwords in this math are assumed to be 100% cryptographically random!